# Почему не обновляется перевод темы woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Скачал тему для woocommerce и заметил, что на страницах кое-где остался английский язык. Нашел .po файл, обновил пункты, которые были нужны, с помощью PoEdit, но на сайте ничего не изменилось. Какие могут быть причины для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `.po` надо сохранить. При этом автоматически будет скомпилирован файл `.mo`, который и нужен на сайте. Файл с полным именем `woocommerce-ru_RU.mo` должен находиться в папке

```
/wp-content/languages/woocommerce/woocommerce-ru_RU.mo
```

Здесь он не будет изменён при обновлении WooCommerce.

P.S. Часто шаблоны WooCommerce перекрываются темами, которые используют свой текстовый домен для переводов. В этих случаях часть сообщений может остаться без перевода. Надо смотреть в коде темы, какой там текстовый домен, и обновлять его перевод.

Переводы тем находятся в папке

```
/wp-content/languages/themes/имя-темы-ru_RU.mo
```

Comment: Вот в этом-то и соль, что я нашел, где находятся файлы .mo и .po темы, и специально нажал на кнопку "Компилировать в формат МО", и ничего

Comment: Я вам дал ответ. Скомпилировать - мало. Надо записать на сайт. Положить именно в эту папку, а не в другую. И убедиться, что эти строки относятся к WooCommerce, а не к теме.

Comment: Я, наверное, неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Перевод woocommerce - полон, и меня он устраивает. А вот тема не переведена. Я всё сохранил и загрузил туда же, откуда взял. Ни названий файлов, ни папок не менял. Выгрузил, исправил, сохранил, загрузил обратно. Итог - ничего

Comment: А откуда взяли? Из какой папки?

Comment: `/wp-content/themes/revoke2/languages`

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Надо в /wp-content/languages/themes/revoke2-ru_RU.mo

Comment: Решение оказалось проще некуда - очевидные для других вещи не были очевидными для меня - я менял файл .po и совсем не подумал о том, что имя файла тоже играет роль. Переименовал из en_US в ru_RU в папке темы и всё заработало